# Chrome's print preview panel closes immediately after loading

Tags: google-chrome

I'm trying to print a page from our website using chrome's (CTRL + P) print, and the problem is that the print preview panel/window immediately closes right after (1-2secs) it loads. I tried it on other websites and it works fine.

I'm not really sure if this is a code (css/js) issue. I have tried disabling the plugin (chrome://plugins/) Chrome PDF viewer as per other people said, clearing cache, re-installing chrome.

Anyone who experienced the same thing?

Comment: The question is [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for StackOverflow. Use https://superuser.com.

Comment: as you wish my lord.

Comment: If you manage to find the actual offending js/css, edit the question accordingly, it'll be on-topic then.

Comment: question transfered to superuser.com
https://superuser.com/questions/1106058/chromes-print-preview-panel-closes-immediately-after-loading

Comment: I think it's worth submitting a bug report to Chrome developers too: 1. open that site 2. click the menu button -> Help -> Report an issue.